# Modal JS error - Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display a modal pop up to show details of a selected record in a grid. After I set the values of each control in modal pop up,i try to open it and it fails.
I have included all required references in site master page but keep getting "Object does not support property or method 'modal'" error:

In Master page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-json/2.6.0/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
```

Javascript:

```
function setDetailFields(record, clear) {debugger
    // populate controls in modal
    var reqID = record["RequestID"];
    ...

    $('#spnRequestID').text(reqID);
    ...

    //$('#detailModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    $('#detailModal').modal('show');
}
```

.aspx:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="detailModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="catModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in modal-lg ui-draggable">
        <div class="modal-content">    
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Something</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"> 
                ...                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

check your references; I think they have conflict to each other.
comment and de-comment the references to find the conflict.
hope it'll be useful

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct

Possible problem :

- You need to apply modal HTML code to the end Master `ContentPlaceHolder` body contant
- Try to keep it's HTML just before ending of `</body>` as near as possible
- Check other elemests `z-index` in css, its might not be overlapping this model
- Make sure that it is calling `$('#detailModal').modal('show');`, use developer toolbar and debugger (You already have applied a `debugger`)

Check below example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myBtn').click(function () {
        setDetailFields();
    })
});

function setDetailFields(record, clear) {
    // populate controls in modal
    //var reqID = record["RequestID"];
    //...

    //$('#spnRequestID').text(reqID);
    //...

    //$('#detailModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    $('#detailModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-json/2.6.0/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<button class='btnup' id="myBtn">Show Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="detailModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="catModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in modal-lg ui-draggable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Something</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying. The issue seemed to be the following two jquery script references in master page. Once I removed them, modal worked.

```
<body>
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptMaster" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```